# Visual Studio Code - How to hide/show the terminal

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

When I create a new terminal in Visual Studio Code, I don't have an option to hide/show the terminal; I only have the option to close it.

I want a shortcut to hide the terminal (show the code only) and a shortcut to show it (show the terminal only)

Here's an image to be more clear:

[image: Terminal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use "exit" to close the terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> to open the terminal.

Edit: use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to show and hide the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Open command palette: `ctrl+shift+p` and enter the follwing commands

- to close panel: `View: Close Panel`
- to maximize panel: `View: Toggle Maximized Panel`

If something else than the terminal is showing in the panel, you can use `Terminal: Focus Terminal` to bring the terminal back in focus.

Or simply drag the top border of the panel with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the code then you can take your cursor on the top of the and then slide down the terminal tab by pressing the left button and scrolling the mouse down or you can do Ctrl + ` to completely hide the terminal.

Click on the "+" sign on the top right corner. You can open multiple terminals at the same time using it and can access any of the terminals at a time. The shortcut for it is Ctrl + Shift + `.

Comment: Top of the what?

Comment: @PeterMortensen hey, why are you reviewing all of my answers??? am i in some kind of review?

Comment: @PeterMortensen top of the terminal window